# Final piece of javascript closures I stil don't understand

Tags: javascript

Lets say we have defined this `function` in the global scope:

```
function createCounter() {
  var counter = 0;

  function increment() {
    counter = counter + 1;

    console.log("Number of events: " + counter);
  }

  return increment;
}
```

In most examples explaining closures I see executing:

```
createCounter();
```

from the global scope would just return the inner function:

```
function increment() {
    counter = counter + 1;

    console.log("Number of events: " + counter);
}
```

Now that makes total sense, because of this line in `createCounter` function declaration

```
return increment;
```

So my question is, why does this:

```
var counter1 = createCounter();

counter1();

Number of events: 1 //result
```

Finally get the function to work?

Essentially aren't `counter1` and `createCounter` both pointers to that inner function which exist in the global scope?

Maybe a better way to ask this is why does `counter1()` work and not just return the inner function like `createCounter` does?

Comment: *"Essentially aren't `counter1` and `createCounter` both pointers to that inner function"* No. `counter1` refers to `function increment()` which is clearly a different function than `function createCounter()`. You could easily verify this by comparing them: `counter1 === createCounter` is `false`. Put differently: `createCounter` returns a new/different function, it does not return itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `createCounter` is a function that returns a separate instance of the `increment` function holding a new closure with a different local `counter` variable.

So yes, you need the extra call to get the separate instance of the function and call that as many times as you wish. Notice that calling createCounter doesn't increase the counter, but calling counter1 or counter2 did increase it.

```
var counter1 = createCounter(); //local counter is still 0
var counter2 = createCounter();
counter1(); // 1
counter2(); // 1
counter1(); // 2
counter2(); // 2
```

Answer (score 2):

`createCounter()` returns you the function without calling it.

You could do `createCounter()()` to call it too without the need for an intermediate variable.

If you also had console output in the outer function, like this, it would be clearer what was happening:

```
function createCounter() {
    console.log("in createCounter");

    var counter = 0;

    function increment() {
        counter = counter + 1;

        console.log("Number of events: " + counter);
    }

    return increment;
}
```

When you call `createCounter()` and save the result in a variable you get the output "in createCounter" but NOT "Number of events". When you call function stored in the variable, you get "Number of events: 1" but NOT "in createCounter".

Answer (score 1):

1. In JS functions are `objects` of type `Function`.
2. `createCounter` is in global scope but `increment` is not.
3. When you call createCounter(), it returns a function which exists in 'createCounter`function scope and there is another variable`counter` in that scope.
4. So when you call the returned function you named `counter1` like `counter1()`, it is called which then increments the counter and logs the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `console.log(counter1)` it is going to print the function as it is just function pointer.

When do `counter1()`, you are invoking the function itself